# Haskell Convert 1-800 Numbers

Tags: haskell

This little app converts 1-800 numbers (with letters) to actual numbers. I'm very frustrated by the insertDashes function as it's very brute force. I'm sure there's a far more elegant solution. I'd appreciate any feedback on anything else though.

```
module Dial
    ( enter,
    stripDashes
    ) where

import Data.Char (ord, toLower, isNumber, intToDigit, isPunctuation)
import System.IO
import Data.List


enter = do
    putStrLn "Enter a phone number"
    num <- getLine
    let converted = insertDashes $ convertLetters $ stripDashes num
    putStrLn $ "You may dial " ++ converted

stripDashes :: String -> String
stripDashes xs = [ x | x <- xs, not (elem x  "-") ]

insertDashes :: String -> String
insertDashes xs = take 1 xs ++ ['-'] ++ take 3 (drop 1 xs) ++ ['-'] ++ take 3 (drop 4 xs) ++ ['-'] ++ take 4 (drop 7 xs) 

getDigit :: Char -> Int
getDigit letter
    | (ord letter >= 97) && (ord letter <= 99) = 2
    | ord letter <= 102 = 3
    | ord letter <= 105 = 4
    | ord letter <= 108 = 5
    | ord letter <= 111 = 6
    | ord letter <= 115 = 7
    | ord letter <= 118 = 8
    | ord letter <= 122 = 9
    | otherwise = 0

convertLetters :: String -> String
convertLetters xs = map (\x -> if (isNumber x) then x else (intToDigit $ getDigit $ toLower x)) xs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Type signatures

Good job on providing all type signatures. Unfortunately, you forgot one: `enter`. Always include type signatures on top-level functions.

## Remove unused imports

You use neither `Data.List`, nor `System.IO`.

## Prefer character comparison instead of `ord x > n`

In `getDigit`, you compare characters by their `ord` values. That's not easy on the eye. It's a lot easier to read if you just compare the letter with characters:

```
getDigit :: Char -> Int
getDigit letter
    | letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'c' = 2
    | letter <= 'f' = 3
    | letter <= 'i' = 4
    | letter <= 'l' = 5
    | letter <= 'o' = 6
    | letter <= 's' = 7
    | letter <= 'v' = 8
    | letter <= 'z' = 9
    | otherwise = 0
```

There are other ways to write `getDigit`, but I they differ on personal preference only.

## Use the standard library

`stripDashes` is `filter (/= '-')` in disguise:

```
stripDashes xs = [ x | x <- xs, not (elem x  "-")]
               = [ x | x <- xs, x /= '-']
               = filter (/= '-') xs
```

Therefore use `filter` instead of a list comprehension:

```
stripDashes :: String -> String
stripDashes = filter (/= '-')
```

By the way `not (elem x y)` is `notElem x y`.

## Prefer local bindings instead of long lines

This is personal preference, but I think that

```
convertLetters :: String -> String
convertLetters xs = map toDigit xs
  where
    toDigit x 
     | isNumber x = x 
     | otherwise  = intToDigit $ getDigit $ toLower x
```

is easier to read.

## Use `hlint` to get rid of redundant brackets

You have a lot of redundant brackets, which can make the code hard to read. [`hlint`](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint#readme) can report them to you. It also reports the `not (elem x y) == notElem x y` hint, by the way.

## Prefer pure functions if possible

You have `enter` for a complete transformation. It would be great if there was a non-IO variant too, e.g.

```
convert :: String -> String
convert = insertDashes . convertLetters . stripDashes
```

That way you can export `enter`, `conver` and `stripDashes`.

## Use `splitAt` instead of `take`/`drop` combinations

Finally, we have a look at `insertDashes`. First of all, let's write bindings:

```
insertDashes :: String -> String
insertDashes xs = group1 ++ ['-'] ++ group2 ++ ['-'] ++ group3 ++ ['-'] ++ group4 
   where
      group1 = take 1 xs
      group2 = take 3 (drop 1 xs)
      group3 = take 3 (drop 4 xs)
      group4 = take 4 (drop 7 xs)
```

That looks like a perfect job for `splitAt`:

```
-- do not include this function in your code, it's part of the Prelude
splitAt n xs = (take n xs, drop n xs)
```

However, if we were to rewrite `insertDashes` with `splitAt`, it wouldn't get any better immediately:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

insertDashes :: String -> String
insertDashes xs = group1 ++ ['-'] ++ group2 ++ ['-'] ++ group3 ++ ['-'] ++ group4 
   where
      (group1,ys1) = splitAt 1 xs
      (group2,ys2) = splitAt 3 ys1
      (group3,ys3) = splitAt 3 ys2
      (group4,_  ) = splitAt 4 ys3
```

Ugh. Not really any better. So instead let's write another function:

```
splitAtNs :: [Int] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitAtNs []     xs = [xs]
splitAtNs (n:ns) xs = as : splitAtNs ns bs
  where (as, bs) = splitAt n xs
```

Now  `insertDashes` is

```
insertDashes :: String -> String
insertDashes xs = group1 ++ ['-'] ++ group2 ++ ['-'] ++ group3 ++ ['-'] ++ group4 
   where
      (group1:group2:group3:group4:_) = splitAtNs [1,3,3,4] xs
```

Which almost looks fine. There is one more improvement, though. The function `intercalate` from `Data.List` brings it down to a single line:

```
insertDashes :: String -> String
insertDashes = intercalate "-" . take 4 . splitAtNs [1,3,3,4]
```

Comment: This is FANTASTIC feedback. Thank you for taking to the time and for being so thorough!

Comment: @JimWharton thanks for YOUR feedback, highly appreciate it. By the way, do you know [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) yet?

Comment: I do not. Most of my playing has been how do I <do this thing I've done in some other language for years>? That's not the best way to learn idiomatic Haskell, I'm certain. I've owned a copy of LYAH for about 4 years and haven't really applied it. This year I've been working with OCaml, F# and Haskell just for fun. These resources look great!